# Use Dagger's @Provides annotation on Kotlin propery

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

When explicitly providing services from Dagger's modules, I can use the following syntax:

```
@Provides
fun provideService(): MyService = MyService()
```

However, if I try to use property instead of a function, it doesn't work:

```
@Provides
val myService get() = MyService()
```

The error I get is: `This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property without backing field or delegate'`.

The approach with a property feels like it should work, but it doesn't.

My question is whether there is a way to use properties to provide services from Dagger modules?

Comment: `@get:Provides` but why not just use function?

Comment: @IR42, thanks, it works, just like mahdi's answer. I did go with a function, but wanted to know how to make this work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```kotlin
val myService: MyService 
    @Provides get() = MyService()
```